# RegEx more than multiple characters before number

Tags: regex

I really don't use RegEx that much. You could say I am RegEx n00b. I have been working on this issue for a half a day.

I am trying to write a pattern that looks backward from a number character. For example:

```
1. bob1 => bob
2. cat3 => cat
3. Mary34 => Mary
```

So far I have this `(?![A-Z][a-z]{1,})([A-Za-z_])`
It only matches for individual characters, I want all the characters before the number character. I tried to add the `^` and `$` into my pattern and using an [online simulator](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F!%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-z%5D%7B1%2C%7D%29%28%5BA-Za-z_%5D%29&i=enc_id1). I am unsure where to put the `^` and `$`.

NOTE: I am using RegEx for the .NET Framework

Comment: Are you trying to match letters before a digit? [`\p{L}+(?=\d)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cp%7bL%7d%2b%28%3f%3d%5cd%29&i=bob1+%3d%3e+bob%0d%0acat3+%3d%3e+cat%0d%0aMary34+%3d%3e+Mary)?

Comment: Could you please explain: 1) are these strings standalone strings? 2) what are the rules here, when the string should be matched, why? Show your code to understand the issue better.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use a look-ahead here? I find that direct matches usually work better in most cases (and are generally more portable).

Comment: @KyleA If OP uses a tool that can only return *matches*, the capturing group based regex will be useless.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What you wrote is close to what I needed. I forgot to mention i also want to include upper and lower case and also '_', but I think I can run with what you have

Comment: `\p{L}` matches both upper- and lowercase letters. To also match `_`, use `[\p{L}_]`

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regex like

```
[\p{L}_]+(?=\d)
```

or

```
[\w-[\d]]+(?=\d)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cw-%5B%5Cd%5D%5D%2B%28%3F%3D%5Cd%29&i=bob1%20%3D%3E%20bob%0D%0Acat3%20%3D%3E%20cat%0D%0AMary34%20%3D%3E%20Mary)

**Pattern details**

- `[\p{L}_]+` - any 1 or more letters (both lower- and uppercase) and/or `_`

  OR
- `[\w-[\d]]+` - 1 or more word chars *except* digits (the `-[]` inside a character class is a character class subtraction construct)
- `(?=\d)` - a positive lookahead that requires a digit to appear immediately to the right of the current location

Comment: Sorry, but the words can also NOT have a number. If there is not a number then match the whole word.. how would I go about that?

Comment: @PeterSun Remove the lookahead if you do not need to restrict the context for letter chunks. However, it is not in the scope of the current question. It would be best to provide *exact* rules for extraction. Otherwise, it will look like a guessing game, and I am very bad at guessing what even my interlocutor does not know they want.

Answer (score 0):

If we break down your RegEx, we see:

`(?![A-Z][a-z]{1,})` which says "look ahead to find a string that is NOT one uppercase letter followed one or more lowercase letters" and `([A-Za-z_])` which says "match one letter or underscore". This should end up matching any single lowercase letter.

If I understand what you want to achieve, then you want all of the letters before a number. I would write something like that as:

```
\b([a-zA-Z]+)[0-9]
```

This will start at a word boundary `\b`, match one or more letters, and require a digit right after the matched string.

(The syntax I used seems to match this document about .NET RegEx: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions)

In light of Wiktor Stribizew's comment, here is a pure match RegEx:

```
\b[a-zA-Z_]+(?=[0-9])
```

This matches the pattern and then looks ahead for the digit. This is better than my first lookahead attempt. (Thank you Wiktor.)

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html